# Linux can't see any of my partitions — The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk

Tags: linux, partition, hard-disk, gpt

I'm trying to install Linux on my HP Pavilion 14 inch ultrabook, but without any success.

At first I tried installing Ubuntu on it; everything went fine, I got into the Live DVD (yes I'm oldschool like that), and went to install the system on my disk. First weird thing that happened was that I wasn't prompted with the option to install Ubuntu alongside Windows, but instead got thrown directly into the window with the partition table. Or rather, lack thereof.

You see, the window showed my drive as being `sda`, but no partitions are visible. None. Not the one with windows on it, not any of the ones windows requires, not even the 500 GB free space on my drive that I made specifically for Ubuntu to play on. None of it.

I then went on to try and install Arch on my machine instead, hoping the more barebones system would be able to see my partitions. And indeed it did not. Exact same story as before, it can see the hard drive, but it cannot see any of the partitions.

This bugs me endlessly and I haven't been able to find any information about this on-line.

So what can I do? Is there some kind of trick to make the partition table visible? Everything else seems to be working, even the WLAN card (the one thing I always have trouble with) works. Any help?

NOTE: The ultrabook came with Windows 8

Output of `sudo fdisk -l` as requested:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn
't support GPD. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121126 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0d5e6520

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundry.

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn
't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sdb: 24.0 GB, 24015495168 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2908 cylinders, total 46905264 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x71dea371

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Trying to run parted gives me the following error:

```
Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk, as it should be.
This might mean that another operating system believes the disk is smaller.
Fix by moving the backup to the end (and removing the old backup)?
```

Following the suggestions below, I tried running `sudo gdisk /dev/sda` and got the following:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
```

What should I do here?

Comment: @Electric Coffee - you never mention the Arch/Ubuntu versions you're trying to install - and you also don't mention anything about the firmware. I would guess an *ultrabook* has got an ssd and you're booting from USB, yes? You need to make sure that the USB disk you create is *also* a UEFI-compatible boot disk - GPT, FAT format, and none of that nonsense with writing a CD iso to the head of the disk - no matter the 100s of tutorials tell you otherwise. You also need to ensure that the firmware is configured to boot EFI. You may need to boot EFI to read EFI with live disks.

Comment: @mikeserv I honestly have no idea what HP model it is, as it doesn't actually say anywhere on it. The hard drive is a HDD, not an SSD, and I'm booting from a DVD, it even states in the question that I'm booting from a DVD... on the second line

Comment: Doesn't sound very *ultra* - what version of Ubuntu - and is the CD booted in EFI mode? Try... `ls /sys/firmware/efi` and if you have booted EFI you *should* show up files in that directory.

Comment: @mikeserv Hey, it says "ultrabook" on the outside, and I got it new. But anyway the command you wanted me to enter spits out `efivars systab vars`

Comment: Still, what Ubuntu version? And I was only joshing you about the ultra thing. I don't care if you have a mega laptop, man. I'm just trying to help. Hmm... My mistake - on my machine `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars
` is the `efivarfs` mountpoint. So you need to go one deeper to check - anything in there?

Comment: @mikeserv a lot of efi vars... i.e. names like Boot and ConIn followed by weird hex numbers; there are between 30 and 50 of them (didn't actually count)

Comment: Yup - you've booted efi. The disk hasn't got any kind of encryption on it, does it? Like... what's the windows thing... Damn. I forget what it's called... Oh! `BitLocker` - or maybe there is a firmware safety boot issue...? A lot of laptop manufacturers setup passwords for disks that self-lock nowadays, too. And if you've got a fancy TPM in your mega laptop you're not gonna be able to get around it short of a soldering iron. Or, you can check some settings in firmware and Windows - such things can usually be disabled in a friendly way.

Comment: @mikeserv the windows partition is available from nautilus, but I'm unable to access it because the disk contains an "unclean file system (0,0)"

Comment: I don't know what that means. You can get a lot more information about the partition table on the disk in `gdisk` as I suggested before - you'll want to try `?` first, and also `man gdisk`. `i` and `p` are both good commands. don't do `w`rite-out until you're definitely ready - if you obey that one rule you can mess around in there as much as you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21168/discussion-between-electric-coffee-and-mikeserv).

Answer (score 0):

This disk is partitioned in the new GPT style, and your current version of `fdisk` doesn't support it. It even says so right at the beginning:

```
WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't 
support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
```

What the `fdisk` is currently showing you is the "protective MBR" of GPT partitioning: on every GPT-partitioned disk, there is a dummy MBR that has a single partition with a type code of `ee`. It is not a real partition: its purpose is just to tell any GPT-unaware operating system or partitioning tool "this disk is not empty: it is in use by something you don't understand".

Because of this, `fdisk`'s report of `Partition 1 does not start at a physical sector boundary` can be ignored... but you probably should not be using that version of `fdisk` to partition that disk at all. You should use `gdisk`, `parted` or a newer version of `fdisk` that supports GPT partitioning. (However, at the time the question was written, such a version of `fdisk` may not have been available yet.)

---

The `Error: The backup GPT table is not at the end of the disk...` you got from `parted` is probably caused by the ultrabook firmware trying to hide an OS recovery partition (or something else) at the end of the disk. Linux is clever enough to see through this hiding attempt.

You could probably gain some useble disk space by allowing `parted` to implement the fix it's suggesting, but in the process you would probably lose the ability to restore the ultrabook's factory-default Windows 8 without using an external Windows installation media... personally, I would regard that as a very acceptable loss :-)